# CSS: match element which contains nothing but an empty element

Tags: css

How would I do this? For example, if I wanted to match all `<p>` tags which contain nothing but an empty `<span>`? Is this possible without modifying the DOM or using JavaScript?

Comment: CSS can't detect the contents of elements. You'd need JavaScript.

Comment: You can find them with javascript/jquery and set css accordingly.

Comment: @user2930185 that will select the empty `spans`, not their parent `p` as the OP wants.

Comment: @j08691 No, but it can detect empty elements, and elements that contain elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. Why?  There's an `:empty` selector which works like in the following example:

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <p> blah </p>
    <p> blah 2 </p> 
</div>

div > p:empty {
    background:red;
}
```

-> The first p would have a red background.

But what you're looking for is something like this

```
div < p:empty {}
```

which would be some kind of parent selector.  At the moment there is no way to accomplish this unfortunately.

Earlier there was a `:contains` selector

```
div:contains(p:empty) {}
```

but it's deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of one way you could do it with JS: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/ELkJa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.empty {background: #e7e7e7; height: 30px;}
.empty::before {content: "Paragraph with empty span!";}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><span>Span 1</span></p>
<p><span>Span 2</span></p>
<p><span></span></p>
<p><span>Span 4</span></p>


<script>
(function() {
    var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    for (var i = 0, ii = span.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var para = span[i].parentNode;
        var paraClasses = para.classList;
        if (!span[i].innerHTML) {
            paraClasses.add('empty');
        }
    }
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As mentioned, there's no parent selector available in CSS, and even though one is proposed, even that will only work with the support of JavaScript.